# font-display: block still results in FOUT

Tags: reactjs, fonts, typekit, gatsby-plugin

I'm using Adobe Typekit for fonts on [my website](https://whereismaurice.com/).

Using Adobe Font's online interface, I've set `font-display` to `block` because going from the local font to the Typekit one tends to be quite jarring. Regardless of the font-display setting, a flash of unstyled text (FOUT) always occurs. What am I doing wrong with my fonts?

It is important to mention my site is Gatsby-based and is using [gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader/).

Answer (score 0):

Switching from [gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader/) to [gatsby-omni-font-loader](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-omni-font-loader/) and using the following configuration in `gatsby-config.js` solved the problem:

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-omni-font-loader`,
      options: {
        mode: `render-blocking`,
        preconnect: [`https://use.typekit.net`],
        web: [
          {
            name: `font1`,
            file: `https://use.typekit.net/${process.env.TYPEKIT_ID}.css`,
          },
          {
            name: `font2`,
            file: `https://use.typekit.net/${process.env.TYPEKIT_ID}.css`,
          },
        ],
      },
    }
```